# physical meaning of the product of arrival rates of two point processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let's say there are a group of buyer and a group of seller that arrive in a market following two Poisson point processes with intensities $\alpha$ and $\beta$. A buyer and a seller may trade with each other when they are "close enough" in time.

In this setup, what would be the physical meaning of the expression $\alpha*\beta$? It looks like it could be something related to the rate of their interactions, but I am not able to derive it. I do not necessary look for an accurate answer, and any heuristic hint would be helpful in pointing me to the right direction.

Better yet, would anyone have any idea what the meaning of $\alpha^c*\beta^c$ might be, with $0<c<1$?  or if this is too far-fetched, what would $\alpha^c$ mean. Thanks a lot!